# Stuck on Project Euler #8

Tags: java

I'm currently working on Project Euler #8.  When I run compile and run the below, I get:

```
Biggest product is 2090188800
```

which isn't correct.  Any idea what I'm doing incorrectly?  Must have something to do with the logic of what I've written but I can't for the life of me figure out where I've mis-stepped.

```
//find greatest product generated by 13 consecutive integers below

class project_euler8 {

    public static final int LENGTH = 13;

    public static String numbers = 
    "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934" +
    "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843" +
    "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511" +
    "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557" +
    "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113" +
    "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749" +
    "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866" +
    "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776" +
    "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243" +
    "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397" +
    "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482" +
    "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474" +
    "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881" +
    "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586" +
    "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042" +
    "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408" +
    "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188" +
    "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606" +
    "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725" +
    "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"; 

    public static int calculateProduct(char[] myArray) {
        int product = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            int number = myArray[i] - '0';
            product *= number;
        }
        return product;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //declare biggest_product, temporary array
        int biggest_product = 0;
        char[] temp = new char[LENGTH];

        //loop through each sequence of 13 integers
        for (int starting_index = 0; starting_index < numbers.length() - LENGTH; starting_index++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
                temp[i] = numbers.charAt(starting_index + i);
            }
            int candidate_product = calculateProduct(temp);
            biggest_product = Math.max(candidate_product, biggest_product);
            starting_index++;
        }
        System.out.println("Biggest product is " + biggest_product);
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help,
Mariogs

Comment: Some information on what you are trying to achieve would be helpful for a start.

Comment: Oh sorry, it's commented out: //find greatest product generated by 13 consecutive integers below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You increment `starting_index` twice so you're skipping ever other number.

Answer (score 3):

[Project Euler Problem 8](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8) states:

> The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.
>
> 73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
>   96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
>   85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
>   12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
>   66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
>   62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
>   30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
>   70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
>   65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
>   52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
>   53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
>   83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
>   82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
>   16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
>   17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
>   24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
>   07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
>   84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
>   05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
>   71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
>
> Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product. What is the value of this product?

In your implementation to find the solution, the problem is that you're using `int` to store the product of the digits, which will overflow. To show an example, the maximum possible value would be the product of 13 consecutive 9s, and the result will be 9^13 = 2541865828329, which is greater than 2^31 - 1 (2147483647).

Use a `long` instead to store the result of the product of digits:

```
public static long calculateProduct(char[] myArray) {
    long product = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        long number = myArray[i] - '0';
        product *= number;
    }
    return product;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I've made the changes you suggested and now get 14108774400 as my ouput.  Unfortunately, this is still incorrect :( Any other suggestion?

Comment: @Mariogs review your code properly and debug through it.